# Setup Eclipse to work with Python bindings for Subversion

Tags: python, eclipse, svn, ubuntu

I'm new in the Python world, coming from PHP. So, this question may sound silly for experienced Python developers, but I'm really confused.

So, I want to implement simple Python app to work with subversion. For that purpose I want to use python bindings for subversion, so I installed Ubuntu python-subversion and python-subversion-dbg packages.

```
$ ll /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.6/libsvn
total 6460
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 2011-12-03 17:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root    4096 2011-12-03 09:47 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  790331 2011-08-05 19:59 _client_d.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  320844 2011-08-05 20:00 _client.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  900465 2011-08-05 19:59 _core_d.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  379804 2011-08-05 20:00 _core.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  300336 2011-08-05 19:59 _delta_d.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  115932 2011-08-05 20:00 _delta.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  228879 2011-08-05 19:59 _diff_d.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   89532 2011-08-05 20:00 _diff.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  345484 2011-08-05 19:59 _fs_d.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  137400 2011-08-05 20:00 _fs.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  582390 2011-08-05 19:59 _ra_d.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  231864 2011-08-05 20:00 _ra.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  491500 2011-08-05 19:59 _repos_d.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  196668 2011-08-05 20:00 _repos.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1038898 2011-08-05 19:59 _wc_d.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  426008 2011-08-05 20:00 _wc.so
```

I tried to add /usr/lib/pyshared/python2.6/libsvn as library in Eclipse from PyDev > Interpreter Python > Libraries > New Folder. But I still can't import anything from svn package. I also see that there are no .py files, just .so.

I just want to be able to use it like on http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch08s02.html

My code:

```
from svn import fs
```

Erro I get:

```
File "/home/umpirsky/EclipseWorkspace/test/src/test.py", line 1, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name fs
```

How can I import this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember installing this a while ago. Did you follow all the step of the? 
The ones that you have to get right are:

- cd Source
- Create the Makefile using 'python setup.py configure'
- make
- cd Tests
- Test pysvn by running make

If that runs you know you are ok with the build. Then install pysvn by copying the following from Extension/Source to python site-specific directory.

```
mkdir python-libdir/site-packages/pysvn
cp pysvn/__init__.py python-libdir/site-packages/pysvn   
cp pysvn/_pysvn*.so python-libdir/site-packages/pysvn
```

By default you site-packages should be under: /usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages

Once you've copied that, on Eclipse:

Window->Preferences->Pydev->Interpreter Python

Under System PYTHONPATH add the folder you created above.

I've found that sometimes Pydev won't pick the new source folder for whatever reason. So, I just remove the compiler and add it again. When you do that Pydev will pick everything up under site-packages.

Edit:
Here are the download [instructions](http://pysvn.tigris.org/project_downloads.html) of what you need. I thought you had downloaded the same package as python-svn. I actually haven't use the distribution you downloaded. But I think pysvn will do the trick for you and it has good documentation if you are just starting.

The install guide should get you going with the install. If you get lost with it refer to the notes that I have above.

site-package is just the standard location for python installed modules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a bit unclear to me because I'm new in this things. Where from do I get sources? What are site-packages? So, I should compile it? What is then this http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/python-subversion package used for? And in that case, how do I deploy app with this dependency?

Comment: adding comment to answer because it's too long

Comment: Thanks, it works now. But this is pysvn, so I an't work like on http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch08s02.html, but like on http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_guide.html. Anyway, I think this will do the work. Stil, I'm not sure how to deploy this app. My idea is that one just installs ubuntu package and it works, so people don't need to compile pysvn by hand. Any hint on that?

Comment: np. If you will deploy your module elsewhere, I would precompile pysvn for those platforms and then create a setup.py for your module. Python has a standard for doing that: take a look at http://docs.python.org/distutils/

Comment: Wow, thanks for the link. I want this to be Ubuntu app, so I will be packaging it as .deb package. I guess same level of automation can be achieved using Distulus in combination with Ubuntu packages. So it can be installed right from Ubuntu Software Center (package manager) or apt get install.